# changing browser specific CSS3 (prefix) properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, coding-style, cross-browser, prefix

So I'm trying to dynamically change the style of a div with javascript, which is normally no big deal except that I'm trying to change some CSS3 properties which have a prefix, i.e. minus (-) in the name... and of course, that means something else entirely in javascript...

so I've got this going on in my javascript:

```
r += 1;
document.getElementById('someDiv').style.transform = "rotate(" + r + "deg)";
```

and my div's style property looks like this:

```
transform: rotate(30deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(50deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Firefox */
```

so that javascript works fine to change the "transform" property, but how would I change the rest of them? because doing something like this won't work:

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').style.-ms-transform = "rotate(" + r + "deg)";
```

because the javascript reads the "-" as syntax error :(

thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of the `-`, make the next letter uppercase: `style.MozTransform`.
(just like `style.backgroundColor`)

Note that IE incorrectly uses `msTransform` with a lowercase `m`.

Comment: Actually, I believe it is `msTransform`.

Comment: Well given that `document.body.style.MsTransform` is undefined and `document.body.style.msTransform` is an empty string, I'd have to say I'm right here.

Comment: Ah yes, Awesome! Thanks so much! I haven't tried on IE or Opera, but this seems to work great on Chrome, Safari, and FireFox :)

Answer (score 2):

In javascript you can access object property trought two ways : dot notation or array notation. In particular when you have special chars in the property name, use array notation :

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').style['-ms-transform'] = "rotate(" + r + "deg)";
```

Then you need to insure that the property is right for the browser, I strongly recommend you to use a javascript lib like jQuery, Mootools, etc if you wana win some time and prevent some frustration that web developpers had before these great tools...

Comment: Because the Javascript property is called `msTransform`.  That will create a new property that the browser will ignore.

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery and just change classes

```
 $("p").removeClass("myClass noClass").addClass("yourClass");
```

Comment: I wish I could up this twice!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the style **inline** you can ignore the prefix and change the degrees.
An element's style.cssText is read and writable.

```
var sty=document.getElementById('someDiv').style;

sty.cssText= sty.cssText.replace(/rotate\([^)]+/,'rotate(30');
```